# Using AMPscript to dynamically supply values to a custom object inside journey builder

Tags: ampscript, journeybuilder, custom-object

I am using a custom Salesforce object to store information related to sending printed pieces that are relevant when someone reaches a specific part of a journey. One of the attributes we want to include in that object is URL, however, the URL we want to store is dynamic based on other attributes for that subscriber.

In our emails, we are populating the URL using a data extension lookup. I tried using the same lookup code when testing the custom object but it just treats that AMPscript as the actual string we want to store.

Is there a way to use AMPscript to send dynamic information to a custom object? Or do I need to find another way to send the dynamic URL?

Comment: What is the relationship between the custom object and the data extension storing the URLs?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The custom object has information related to the printed piece (e.g. address, etc.) but the relevant field here is URL. The subscriber is associated with a location and the URL we want in the printed piece is related to that location. So the data extension relates the subscriber's location and brings back a URL for that location. That's how we are handling the URL dynamically in emails. Per SF support, it seems that I may need to go down a different path with automations / SQL to accomplish this.